# Отображение результатов запросов к БД в C#

Tags: c#

Для отображения SELECT запросов мне известен DataGridView, но он, как я понял, работает только с одной таблицей, и если в строках содержатся ссылки на ключи других таблиц, то подстановку (Сложный запрос) совершить нельзя.

Допустим, что сложный SQL-запрос готов (в TableAdapter), какие есть возможности отображения результата? 
И еще вопрос, что возвращает TableAdapter и как с этим можно работать "ручками"?

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Для отображения SELECT запросов мне известен DataGridView, но он, как
>   я понял, работает только с одной таблицей, и если в строках содержатся
>   ссылки на ключи других таблиц, то подстановку (Сложный запрос)
>   совершить нельзя.

DataGridView работает не с одной таблицей, а с результатом одного запроса TableAdapter, будь то сложный запрос, запрос представления данных. Так что сложный запрос `совершить` можно.